# MapStruct shared config with generics

Tags: generics, mapstruct

I have multiple marker interfaces and MappedSuperclass-es on the entities, and I'd like to create a shared configuration, to ignore some entity specific targets.

Sample interfaces and classes:

```
public interface LongPrimaryKey extends Serializable

public abstract class FeatureBaseEntity extends BaseEntity

public class MyEntity extends FeatureBaseEntity implements LongPrimaryKey
```

I do the following in the MapperConfig interface:

```
@MapperConfig(
    unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, 
    mappingInheritanceStrategy = MappingInheritanceStrategy.AUTO_INHERIT_FROM_CONFIG
)
public interface CentralConfig {

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    LongPrimaryKey toLongPrimaryKey(Model model);

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(target = "modifiedAt", ignore = true)
    })
    BaseEntity toBaseEntity(Model model);

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(target = "modifiedAt", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    })
    <T extends BaseEntity & LongPrimaryKey> T toBaseEntityLongPrimaryKey(Model model);

}

@Mapper(config = CentralConfig.class)
public interface MyEntityMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(...)
    })
    @InheritConfiguration(name = "toBaseEntityLongPrimaryKey")
    MyEntity toMyEntity(MyFeatureModel myFeatureModel, @MappingTarget MyEntity entity);
}
```

This throwing the following:

```
[DEBUG] diagnostic MyEntityMapper.java:28: error: None of the candidates toLongPrimaryKey(), toBaseEntity() matches given name: "toBaseEntityLongPrimaryKey".
    @InheritConfiguration(name = "toBaseEntityLongPrimaryKey")
    ^
[DEBUG] diagnostic MyEntityMapper.java:29: error: More than one configuration prototype method is applicable.
Use @InheritConfiguration to select one of them explicitly: LongPrimaryKey toLongPrimaryKey(Model model), BaseEntity toBaseEntity(Model model).
    MyEntity toMyEntity(MyFeatureModel myFeatureModel, @MappingTarget MyEntity entity);
```

This feature is not covered yet, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's an issue with related to the type variable of `<T>` in your `toBaseEntityLongPrimaryKey()` method. It works when e.g. referencing the `toBaseEntity()` method.

Could you open an issue in [our tracker](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues) for this one, please? Thanks!